# Create a custom metric based on a metric in Google Analytcs

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to setup a dimension based on a metric in Google Analytics

```
Example: Avg. Document Interactive Time (sec) = adit
0 < adit < 100 = Fast
101 < adit < 300 = Average
301 < adit < 600 = Slot
```

So I could use this new dimension to create useful reports.

I tried to use custom segments, but I can find Avg. Document Interactive Time (sec)

Answer (score 1):

Calculated dimensions functionality is not supported in google analytics. something similar may be created in Data Studio reports as a custom field of analytics data source based on CASE formula.
Document interactive time is available as ga:domInteractiveTime metric